# Create a nested list of items from objects with a parent reference

Tags: c#, linq

I am using `C#` and I have a list of items that have a nullable parent ID property.

I need to convert this to a list of items that have a list of their children and keep going down generations until there are no items left.

My existing class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

My first thoughts...

Create a class

```
public class ItemWithChildren
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public List<ItemWithChildren> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need some way to get a `List<ItemWithChildren>` that has all the top level Item objects and their children into the `Children` property.

Note that the nesting is not a set number of levels.

I was hoping there was an elegant LINQ query that would work. So far I just have this...

```
var itemsWithChildren = items.Select(a => new ItemWithChildren{ Item = a });
```

Comment: @CharlesGraham Now that I am back at work I can give these a try, and once I have it working I will mark the correct answer as such.

Comment: @CharlesGraham what's the verdict?

Answer (score 5):

It is more readable to not use pure Linq for this task, but a mixture of Linq and looping.

Given the following container:

```
 class Node
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
 }
```

Then you can make the tree with the following code.

```
    var nodes = new List<Node>
    {
        new Node{ Id = 1 },
        new Node{ Id = 2 },
        new Node{ Id = 3, ParentId = 1 },
        new Node{ Id = 4, ParentId = 1 },
        new Node{ Id = 5, ParentId = 3 }
    };

    foreach (var item in nodes)
    {
        item.Children = nodes.Where(x => x.ParentId.HasValue && x.ParentId == item.Id).ToList();
    }

    var tree = nodes.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue).ToList();
```

This will handle any level of depth and return a proper tree.

---

Given the following method to print the tree:

```
private void PrintTree(IEnumerable<Node> nodes, int indent = 0)
{
    foreach(var root in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", new String('-', indent), root.Id));
        PrintTree(root.Children, indent + 1);
    }
}
```

The output of this call is:

```
1
-3
--5
-4
2
```

---

If however you want to use pure Linq for this, you can do the following, however to me it is harder to read:

```
       var tree = nodes.Select(item =>
        {
            item.Children = nodes.Where(child => child.ParentId.HasValue && child.ParentId == item.Id).ToList();
            return item;
        })
        .Where(item => !item.ParentId.HasValue)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: x.ParentId.HasValue is not necessary in the where as x.ParentId when it is null will never equal item.Id which is not nullable

Comment: @Mick Very true, that is just the overly defensive developer in me coming out.

Comment: @CharlesGraham in the foreach loop the children are added correctly, but after exiting the loop all children are null again. I'm not sure why

Comment: Running this exact code on my machine does not result in the children being null.  I will add an example of the output.

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ Updated with the output.

Comment: There's defensive and then there's redundant

Answer (score 2):

This might help ?

```
var itemsWithChildren = items.Select(a => new ItemWithChildren{ 
                                         Item = a,
                                         Children = items.Where(b => b.ParentId==a.Id)
                                                         .ToList()
                                    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this addresses the nesting that can b n levels deep.

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ I have updated my answer and I think your `List<ItemWithChildren>`  inside of your ItemWithChildren class should be `List<Item>`, otherwise it might be infinite loop.If you want it like that I don't think linq is the best solution try to use a for loop or something

Comment: What's the ".Select(b  => b)" for?

Comment: I think you're close but its not going to work as items.Where is going to return a collection of Item not ItemWithChildren.  I've posted my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Then update model to achieve it as

```
  public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Parent Category")]
    public virtual Guid? CategoryUID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Comment: Add **Virtual** Keyword before list or collection of same entity

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it in two steps...
I've tested and it definitely works...

```
        var items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item { Id = 1, ParentId = null });
        items.Add(new Item { Id = 2, ParentId = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item { Id = 3, ParentId = 1 });
        items.Add(new Item { Id = 4, ParentId = 3 });
        items.Add(new Item { Id = 5, ParentId = 3 });

        var itemsWithChildren = items.Select(a =>
            new ItemWithChildren { Item = a }).ToList();

        itemsWithChildren.ForEach(a =>
                a.Children = itemsWithChildren.Where(b => 
                    b.Item.ParentId == a.Item.Id).ToList());

        var root = itemsWithChildren.Single(a => !a.Item.ParentId.HasValue);

        Console.WriteLine(root.Item.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(root.Children.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(root.Children[0].Children.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(root.Children[1].Children.Count);
```

Output...

1
2
0
2

Comment: This looks like the elegant solution I was after, but it results in all children being null. I cannot figure out why. Same as with the answer from @CharlesGraham

Comment: I've edited the answer.  There were a couple of mistakes, but it is essentially the same in concept.